# Session and casting error [Telerik and C#]

Tags: c#, telerik

I don't how to cast this properly and I don't know if I pass it readable by telerik radgrid. Kindly check.

I have the following codes:
When I try to pass my session to another list type variable, it encountered error. I'm trying to pass session because I Pass it on another aspx.

```
public class Employee
{
int empID;

string employeename;

int age;

string adress;
}

List<Employee> Profile = new List<Employee>();

Session["Emp"] = Profile;

List<Employee> xdata = new List<Employee>();

xdata = (List<Employee>) Session["Emp"];

Radgrid1.Datasource = xdata;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with the below code snippet? It might be possible that you have given inbuilt keyword name to variable so it was giving casting error.

```
public class Employee
{
    int empID;
    string employeename;
    int age;
    string adress;
}


List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
Session["Emp"] = empList;

List<Employee> xdata = (List<Employee>) Session["Emp"];
Radgrid1.Datasource = xdata;
```